# Dependency property value not assigned while setting value through Styles using dynamic resource

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, exception, dependency-properties

```
Public Class UITreeview
    Inherits System.Windows.Controls.TreeView

Public Shared ExpandAllproperty As DependencyProperty
Shared Sub New()
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(GetType(UITreeview), New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(GetType(UITreeview)))
        UITreeview.ExpandAllproperty = UITreeViewItem.IsExpandedProperty.AddOwner(GetType(UITreeview), New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(True, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits))
    End Sub
Public Property ExpandAll As Boolean
        Get
            Return Me.GetValue(ExpandAllproperty)
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            Me.SetValue(ExpandAllproperty, value)
        End Set
    End Property 
....
End Class
```

i have created my own dependency property,which i set using style

```
<Style  TargetType="{x:Type UINat:UITreeview}">
    <Setter Property="ExpandAll" Value="False" />
</Style>
```

but unfortunately I'm getting an error:

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: property.

My objective is to control TreeviewItem.IsExpanded property from Resource XAML.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a new dependency property `ExpandAll` by adding an owner type to an existing dependency property `IsExpanded`.

Use [Register](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597502.aspx) instead of AddOwner to register a new property:

```
Public Shared ReadOnly ExpandAllproperty As DependencyProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ExpandAll", GetType(Boolean), GetType(UITreeView),
        New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(True, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits))
```